# Get sum up of every 2nd day data between a selected date range

Tags: sql-server

I having table like below in Sql Server. I need to get data within in a date range, for example -: **StartDate** = '2020-09-01' and **EndDate** = '2020-09-11'. Its quite simple to get data between a date range but complicated part is that,i need to **Sum** up data in **every 2nd day** in the selected date range.
**For Example -:**
[image]

As in the above image, i need to Sum up of SKU in every 2nd day in single column. Could anyone help me out with the query for this result output.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Sku Nvarchar(50),
    OrderDate DateTime,
    Quantity Int,
)

INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#xyz','2020-09-01 00:00:00.000',2)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#xyz','2020-09-02 00:00:00.000',1)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#xyz','2020-09-03 00:00:00.000',3)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#xyz','2020-09-04 00:00:00.000',4)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#xyz','2020-09-05 00:00:00.000',5)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#xyz','2020-09-06 00:00:00.000',6)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#xyz','2020-09-07 00:00:00.000',2)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#xyz','2020-09-08 00:00:00.000',1)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#xyz','2020-09-09 00:00:00.000',3)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#xyz','2020-09-10 00:00:00.000',1)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#xyz','2020-09-11 00:00:00.000',10)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#abc','2020-09-01 00:00:00.000',1)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#abc','2020-09-02 00:00:00.000',10)
INSERT INTO #Temp(Sku,OrderDate,Quantity)Values('#abc','2020-09-03 00:00:00.000',10)

select * from #Temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` window function to generate a sequence number per `Sku`. Do a `GROUP BY` `(rn - 1) / 2`. `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` is to only consider those with 2 rows

```
; with 
cte as
(
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Sku order by OrderDate)
    from    #Temp
)
select  Sku, sum(Quantity)
from    cte
group by Sku, (rn - 1) / 2
having count(*) = 2
order by Sku , (rn - 1) / 2
```

Use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if you want the result in CSV.

Comment: That's ridiculous

Comment: @SteveC what do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 1):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` and `LAG()` window functions:

```
select Sku, Quantity
from (
  select Sku, 
    row_number() over (partition by Sku order by OrderDate) rn,
    Quantity + lag(Quantity) over (partition by Sku order by OrderDate) Quantity
  from #Temp
  where OrderDate between '20200901' and '20200911'
) t
where rn % 2 = 0 
order by Sku, rn;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ab1b6af9a47b7b6671df1fe1d44cf54a).
Results:

```
> Sku  | Quantity
> :--- | -------:
> #abc |       11
> #xyz |        3
> #xyz |        7
> #xyz |       11
> #xyz |        3
> #xyz |        4
```

Comment: This is working fine in case of 2nd day, but if we change day 3 or 1, it's not giving desire output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
;with
string_cte(Sku, OrderDate, Quantity, rn_grp) as(
    select  *, (row_number() over (partition by Sku order by OrderDate)+1)/2
    from    #Temp),
sum_cte(Sku, rn_grp, sum_quantity) as (
    select Sku, rn_grp, sum(quantity) 
    from string_cte
    group by Sku, rn_grp
    having count(*)>1)
select
  Sku, string_agg(sum_quantity, ',') within group (order by rn_grp) SecondDaySumUp
from sum_cte
group by Sku
order by 1 desc;
```

Output

```
Sku     SecondDaySumUp
#xyz    3,7,11,3,4
#abc    11
```